# How can I create a ssis job to export tables to file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

Im new to ssis ,

I have a table like ↓

```
no  tablename
1    table1
2    table2
3    table3
```

what I want use ssis  to do is ....

1, create a folder as name yyyyMMddhhmmss

2, fetch the table names from above table

3, export all the tables to files with their own name.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic pattern I would use would be to iterate through all the tables and invoke [BCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) against them.

Rough layout would be the following
[image]

Comment: Dear Downvoter ([@TheOptimusPrimus](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2517150/theoptimusprimus)) I see that you've voted this as "not useful". Could you help me understand what is lacking so that I may improve the answer?